# AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN new access token from JWT grant in DocuSign

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi

Trying to read data of specific envelopes from DocuSign using completely backend java process ... and after some trial and error I've obtained AccessToken with JWT grant but still getting authorization error when asking for actual data :(

- Defined new integration key 9xxx7e

  - User Application: Authorization Code Grant
  - No secrets added
  - Service Integration - uploaded public RSA key
  - Added one Redirect URI (regardless I don't need any)
- Manual confirmation of corresponding link : https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=9xxx7e&state=123&redirect_uri=https://my.redirect.net/DocuSign ... assuming it is just one-time action
- Successfully requested Access Token using java code (using com.docusign:docusign-esign-java:3.10.1)

```
ApiClient = new ApiClient(ApiClient.DEMO_REST_BASEPATH);
OAuthToken token = apiClient.requestJWTApplicationToken(integrationKeyJwt, scopes, privateKeyFileContent, 3600);
```

- Trying to get envelope data using simple HttpGet

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/6xxx1e/envelopes");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());
```

- but still got 401 response with content:

`{"errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed. Authentication for System Application failed."}`

Please any idea what is wrong? How to obtain correct Access Token?

P.S.: I also tried to get Authorization Code Grant without JWT or implicit grant but no luck without browser tough :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you print the `accessToken` you're creating in a file and use in Postman. This will at least help you narrow it down to either the Token generation step or sending the request portion.

Let us know what you find.

Comment: Sure - tried that already with no success - curl behaves completely the same - still the 401 and the same json response :(

Comment: How long do you wait between getting the accessToken and trying it in Postman?

Comment: Also validate `privateKeyFileContent` contains the secret. I.e. you read the secret from file or env correctly.

Comment: Tried to switch certificates (used DocuSign generated one now) with the same result - if I use old one then DocuSign won't give me any accessToken hence I assume my certificate manipulation is OK. And I'm requesting data immediately when I get the token -  or after few secs/mins based on used breakpoints

Comment: Thanks @Nima in the end problem was with Application vs User token

Answer (score 0):

Problem was/is with use of apiClient.requestJWTApplicationToken but apiClient.requestJWTUserToken is the way to go